# Aurelia components element and jQuery closest function

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, aurelia

I miss understand why such code return empty array. I try to implement simple logic, when I click outside control wana close the popup.

The problem `$(elem).closest('custom-popup')` always empty array, when I click inside the control. I'm doing something like that.

**code.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class CustomPopup {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element
    }

    attached() {
       $(document).on('click', e => this.cancelEvent(e));
    }

    cancelEvent(e){
       elem = e.target;
       if (elem !== this.element && $(elem).closest('custom-popup')[0] !== this.element)
         $(this.element).toggleClass('hide');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `console.log(e.target.outerHTML)` to your cancel method.  That might shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: `console.log(e.target.outerHTML)` show me html inside `<template>` tag

Comment: You should be able to do this without jquery, that's kinda the point of using a framework like Aurelia. I'm unsure of your html but does your component also display a background overlay with your popup content on top? In that case, you should be able to bind to click events (`click.delegete(someFunc)`) on the overlay, and then use `if.bind` or `visible.bind` to show/hide the popup. If you share your html template I can provide a more detailed answer